# HTTP2 expects streams to be opened following the sequence

Tags: protocols, http2

I haven't seen this claim in the official HTTP2 spec but it seems that if you open streams with IDs that do not represent sequential numbers, the server responds with a GoAway frame having ProtocolError as a reason.

Example (INVALID):

```
=> HEADER{sid: 3}
=> HEADER{sid: 1}
<= GoAway{ProtoclError}
```

Example (VALID):

```
=> HEADER{sid: 1}
=> HEADER{sid: 3}
<= ... All good ...
```

Why is that? Can someone point me to the right section in the spec, pelase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is stated in the [HTTP/2 specification, section 5.1.1]:(https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-5.1.1)

> The identifier of a newly established stream MUST be numerically
> greater than all streams that the initiating endpoint has opened or
> reserved.
> ...
> An endpoint that
> receives an unexpected stream identifier MUST respond with a
> connection error (Section 5.4.1) of type PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Comment: Got it. It wasn't clear that it means "already SENT" frames.

Comment: It does not mean "already SENT". For example, the stream id may be allocated and the first frame for that stream enqueued for send, but not actually sent, as long as there is some guarantee that the allocation of the stream id and the enqueueing of the first frame for that stream is "atomic" (i.e. it does not get overtaken by a greater stream id). The queue may be committed to the network later, preserving the order.

Comment: Sorry for my inappropriate articulation. What I meant is that in the case when the other side receives a greater unknown ID (e.g 3) and after that a lower ID (e.g. 1), for the first time, the other side treats this as a Protocol Error. So you have to start a stream by sending the HEADERS or PRIORITY frame to the other side where their IDs must be in a sequence (ok: 1, 3 ..., err: 3, 1).